# Putting limits on access to public S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, blobstorage

We developed a new Python data analysis toolbox that we're in the process of trying to share publicly. We like to share Jupyter notebooks as code examples, with a public AWS S3 bucket containing example data for folks to use.

Is there a way to limit the rate of access to data shared this way?

It's very small (< 1 GB), so storage costs are low, but I fear large numbers of accesses driving up our costs. Or is there a good alternative for public sharing of binary blobs?

Comment: Related https://chrisshort.net/the-aws-bill-heard-around-the-world/